# How to get meta box data to display on a page

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I am trying to piece together a Metabox with 3 text editor fields for a custom post type.

The box is showing up and appears to be saving on the custom post type entries but I can't get the data to display on the single-[custom-post-type].php page.

Most recently I have tried the following to get the meta box data to display on the page:

```
global $post;
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my-info', true ); 
if ($meta != '') {
    echo $meta
} else { 
    echo "Can't Display The Content";
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a problem with my Metabox creation/save that I can't get it to display. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Here is a link to the code that I'm using for my Metabox if it helps:

[Metabox Code](http://pastebin.com/KKQG47nV)

Comment: Any progress on that question?

Answer (score 8):

To show post type meta data on a single page template, I assume that you're in the Loop.

```
// Use get_the_ID() to get the ID via the API function
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my-info', true );
// You can also call it from the global, as the query refers to the current single page
echo get_post_meta( $GLOBALS['post']->ID, 'my-info', true );
```

If you're not getting *any* output, then you might want to check your complete set of post custom data:

```
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', var_export( get_post_custom( get_the_ID() ), true ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use IDs of fields to get meta data of respective fields as following code.

```
global $post;
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'myinfo-box1', true); // Use myinfo-box1, myinfo-box2, myinfo-box3 for respective fields
if ($meta != '') {
    echo $meta;
} else { 
    echo "Can't Display The Content";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$m_meta_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'images_url',true);

echo 'meta box value: ' . $m_meta_description;
```

Comment: Could you explain why this will solve the problem?

Answer (score -2):

Some times **id** is not working then we can use **name** attribute.

For displaying meta box values your code **must be in loop.**

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'meta-box-text', true);
```

Here **meta-box-text** is name attribute of my input text field.

It works perfect for me.

Comment: Why? Why do you think that it has to be in the loop? The first param for this function is `post_id` so you CAN use it anywhere, not only in the loop. Sorry, but your answer is just wrong.